# PDOStatement::fetch() and duplicate field names

Tags: php, pdo

I'm working on a web application using MySQL and PHP 5.3.8. We have a mechanism to translate a simplified query instruction into a complete query string, including joins.

Since I cannot know what (normalized) tables there will be joined and what their fields are called, there may be duplicate field names. When executing `PDOStatement::fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`, I get an associated array of field names:

```
$test = $this->DBConnection->prepare("SELECT `events`.`Title`, `persons`.`Title` FROM `events` JOIN `persons` ON `events`.`HostID` = `persons`.`ID`;");
$test->execute();
$test->fetch();
```

But I have no way of distinguishing repeating field names, such as "title". Worse, duplicates overwrite each other:

```
array('Title' => 'Frodo Baggins');
```

In the bad old days, I ran `mysql_fetch_field()` on each field to get the table for each field. Please, tell me there is a better way than prefixing the fields (`SELECT events.Title AS eventsTitle;`).

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You could do `Group By` as you would with MySQL but depending on how you add the data to the database it could disallow a lot or allow everything as that field may not be even slightly important. // After looking.. of no use

Comment: What does that have to do with the question?

Comment: Yeah I only realised what the question was really asking when I saw your none-answer "answer".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Give them aliases in the query so they won't be duplicates:

```
SELECT events.Title AS eTitle, persons.Title AS pTitle FROM ...
```

Then the row will be:

```
array('eTitle' => 'Hobbit Meeting', 'pTitle' => 'Frodo Baggins');
```

The alternative is to fetch the result as an indexed array rather than associative:

```
$test->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
```

Then you'll get:

```
array('Hobbit Meeting', 'Frodo Baggins');
```

and you can access them as `$row[0]` and `$row[1]`.

Comment: Thanks. Is that the only way?

Comment: Added an alternative using `PDO::FETCH_NUM`.